# How to use pagination in Kendo grid with partial views in mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-grid, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am using Kendo grid to show some user information. I have 3 tabs in view Admin and each of the tab is partial view. say customer,user,portfolio. i am loading the kendo grid while calling the main view itself which is Admin View through view Model which consists 3 classes

```
public class AdminViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<CustUser> CustomerUsers { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Portfolio> Portfolios { get; set; }
}
```

And i am passing this view model to each of the 3 partial views. And its working fine but the problem is when i want to go to the next page in Grid. Its just returning the Json Data on the page.
My kendo grid:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
            @try
            {
                @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.CustomerUsers)
            .Name("User")
            .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(p => p.CustUserID).Visible(false);
                        columns.Bound(p => p.FirstName);
                        columns.Bound(p => p.LastName);
                        columns.Bound(p => p.CustUserName);
                        columns.Bound(p => p.EmailAddress);
                        columns.Bound(p => p.IsActive);
                        columns.Bound(p => p.ModifiedDt).Visible(false);
                        columns.Bound(p => p.CreatedDt).Visible(false);
                        columns.Command(command =>
                        {
                            //command.Edit();
                            //command.Destroy().Text("Del");
                            command.Custom("Delete").Click("ConfirmDeleteUnit").Text("<span class='fa fa-trash-o'></span>").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "width:40px !important;min-width:0px !important;" }); ;
                        }).Width(160);
                    })
               .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable(scrollable => scrollable.Virtual(true))
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()

                        .PageSize(25)
                            .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                        .Model(model =>
                            {
                                model.Id(i => i.CustUserID);

                            })

                                .Read(read => read.Action("LazyCustUser_Read", "Admin")
                                )
                    //.Update(update => update.Action("InlineEditUnit_Update", "Unit"))
                    //.Destroy(update => update.Action("InlineEditUnit_Destroy", "Unit"))
             )
                )
            }
            catch (Exception exe)
            {

                CSP.Web.Helpers.Log objLog = new CSP.Web.Helpers.Log();
                objLog.LogError(exe.Message.ToString() + this.ToString());
            }
        </div>
```

and My Admin Controller

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {


        if (Session["custUserID"] != null)
        {
            try
            {
                var custUsers = await _custUserRepo.GetAllCustUsers();
                var customers = await _CustomerRepo.GetAllCustomers();
                var portfolios = await _portfolioRepo.GetPortFolios();
                if (custUsers == null)
                    return RedirectToAction("ShowError", "Error");
                adminViewModel.CustomerUsers = custUsers;
            }
            catch (Exception exe)
            {
                objError.LogError(exe.Message);
                return RedirectToAction("ShowError", "Error");
            }
            return View(adminViewModel);
        }
        else
        {

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
        }
    }


public async Task<ActionResult> LazyCustUser_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        if (Session["custUserID"] != null)
        {
            try
            {
                var custUser = await _custUserRepo.GetAllCustUsers();
                return Json(custUser.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception exe)
            {
                Log objLog = new Log();
                objLog.LogError(exe.InnerException.ToString());
                return RedirectToAction("ShowError", "Error");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
        }

    }
```

Comment: you need server paging or client paging

Comment: I need client Paging

Comment: there no special handling need for client paging , just turn on paging on the grid and return all the data to the DataSource

Comment: cwishva- do you have any idea about how to get client machine name, domain when application is hosted to server.. i have tried in number of ways but when i hosted to server i'm getting server name instead of client machine name.

Comment: have no idea why you need it , try this http://codingresource.blogspot.com/2010/02/get-client-mac-address-ip-address-using.html

Comment: Actually i need this scenario in AD login, for AD(active directory) login we need to pass client machine name and domain. so i have written code in c# but it is taking server details when i hosted it to server.

Comment: ya because the C# code it executed in the server , only js is will be executed on client , you will have to send it from js to the server .